# mysql LIKE query takes >1 minute but mix LIKE + MATCH/AGAINST 1 second

Tags: mysql, sql-like, match-against

I have a small table with 3 fields and 5 million rows:

fields are Id, DEPTAIRPORT, ARRAIRPORT, DEPT/ARR fields are FULLTEXT indexed

WHen running this code it takes >1 minute to get a result:

```
SELECT * FROM test_copy 
WHERE 
DEPTAIRPORT LIKE 'buenos%' AND 
ARRAIRPORT LIKE 'tokyo%';
```

However when I use this query, it takes 1 second:

```
SELECT * FROM test_copy 
WHERE 
DEPTAIRPORT LIKE 'buenos%' AND 
MATCH (ARRAIRPORT) AGAINST ('tokyo*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Using two MATCH/AGAINST (instead of LIKE) also take >1 minute.

Question: Why two LIKE take so long while using LIKE and MATCH/AGAINST is so fast ?

My main concern is the final table will have 10 fields (and >30 million records), and the search criteria will will then be more complex, including LIKE on other fields....but if just two LIKE are causing such delay I would like to fix the problem before proceeding...

EDIT:
Fields are FULLTEXT.
EXPLAIN shows for 1st query (LIKE + LIKE):

```
select_type:SIMPLE
type:ALL
possible_keys: DEPTAIRPORT,ARRAIRIPORT
key: NULL
ley_len:NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 4444841
extra: USING WHERE
```

EXPLAIN shows for 2nd query (LIKE + MATCH/AGAINST):

```
select_type:SIMPLE
type:FULLTEXT
possible_keys: DEPTAIRPORT,ARRAIRIPORT
key: ARRAIRIPORT
key_len:0
ref: NULL
rows: 1
extra: USING WHERE
```

2nd EDIT:
I have restarted HeidiSQL and now the LIKE+LIKE query takes 10 seconds (before >1 minute).
Looks strange....

Comment: We need explain output of both querys and show create table test_copy output..

Comment: You almost certainly have defined a `FULLTEXT` index over `(ARRAIRPORT)`, hence the performance advantage from using `MATCH (ARRAIRPORT) AGAINST (...)`.

Comment: @raymond, see edit with EXPLAIN

Comment: @eggyal, both fields have FULLTEXT index

Comment: Right.  So what's the question?  `LIKE` doesn't use fulltext indexes; only `MATCH () AGAINST ()` does.

Comment: @user1135218 http://sqlfiddle.com maybe you can also place here your create tables statement and some example data  if mine answer doens't work..

Comment: @eggyal, sorry what I am trying to find out is why 2 (or more) LIKE is taking so long...so far there are only 5 million records, but final table will have >30 million. If it now takes 10 seconds for result (with only 2 LIKE), I can imagine a 30 seconds+ wait when there are 30 million...I need to be very fast, so I am trying to understand if I am doing something wrong (I am pretty new at mysql)

Comment: @user1135218 ive removed mine answer just read that you have two fulltext indexes  LIKE operator can only work with normal indexes (BTree).. but if your DEPTAIRPORT has only buenos you should change the datatype but i need the create table statement and some example data then

Comment: Ok, thanks, thats the answer I was looking for! LIKE doesn't work very well on FULLTEXT indexed fields...I just converted both fields to KEY indexes and all runs fast. In fact I wanted those fields to be FULLTEXT in order to do full LIKE '%xxxxx%' but it seems performance is affected when too many rows...